# Show MySQL host via SQL Command

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Show Database
Use database
show tables
Describe <table>
```

All good and well, but is it possible to show the current connections host.
Not connection_id, but the IP Address or Name of the host.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

To get current host name :-

```
select @@hostname;
show variables where Variable_name like '%host%';
```

To get hosts for all incoming requests :-

```
select host from information_schema.processlist;
```

Based on your last comment,
I don't think you can resolve IP for the hostname using pure mysql function,
as it require a network lookup, which could be taking long time.

However, mysql document mention this :-

```
resolveip google.com.sg
```

docs :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resolveip.html

Comment: I don't have a remote host to test on ATM, but "SELECT @@hostname" gives my local host. If the MySQL session is connected to a different host will it show the remote hosts name? Can I get IP?

Comment: Yes, it will show different host if you come from other host. However, to resolve the corresponding IP is bit hard ...

Comment: Is it possible to get IP from My-SQL? That would be great. Up one vote for @@Hostname, thank you!! Will accept if not possible on IP

Comment: Using command line, get the current connected remote host IP within SQL. Reason, longevity of a script I can't be 100% sure within my code that we're connected to the same host!!

Comment: Malaysian, but Singapore PR.

Comment: Be carefull: these variables deliver the LOCAL hostname of the server. if server is behind a router you will NOT get the internet-hostname of this machine, even if you run this command from "outside"

Answer (score 19):

Maybe

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

Comment: This is a bad suggestion if you're trying to access remotely.

Answer (score 10):

I think you try to get the remote host of the conneting user...

You can get a String like 'myuser@localhost' from the command:

```
SELECT USER()
```

You can split this result on the '@' sign, to get the parts:

```
-- delivers the "remote_host" e.g. "localhost" 
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1) 

-- delivers the user-name e.g. "myuser"
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1)
```

if you are conneting via ip address you will get the ipadress instead of the hostname.

Answer (score 7):

```
show variables where Variable_name='hostname';
```

That could help you !!

Comment: Interesting mine return nothing with this.

Comment: This returns the server hostname, not the client hostname for the connection, as requested ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe ... in the question, it was asked for the Host name only, not the client..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a boot at MySQL and all start working as expected... app server connecting to MySQL, all in different servers, Ubuntu Linux.

```
$ mysql -u sysprod -p -h dbprod --protocol=TCP
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 13
Server version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> select user();
+----------------------------+
| user()                     |
+----------------------------+
| sysprod@dbprod |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```