# How do I find the name of database MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

customer gave me all the information to connect to the database except the host name.

Is there any way to find out yourself what is the name?

Thanks,
Kropamk

Comment: go to the database which is created online you will see phpmyadmin like screen on top you will see host name....same as PHPMYADMIN show..

Comment: What's wrong with asking the customer to also tell you the host name?

Comment: What do you want to find, host name or database name? The question title and the question body both imply something different. The name of the selected database can be retrieved by `select DATABASE();`.

Comment: I have a password, the user but do not have a host name

Comment: A host name is always required. Ask the customer to provide the host name.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8283248/1037210) question, if it can help though I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need the host name or IP.

Answer (score 0):

Run following queries after in mysql command line client:

```
use information_schema;

select distinct table_schema from information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: Host name is always required

Answer (score 0):

If You are using PHP, then for finding hostname use below code:-

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

and for finding **database name** in PHP use below code. The below code will give You the full list of databases.

```
// Usage without mysql_list_dbs()
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['Database'] . "\n";
}
```