# 000webhost website database connection Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, web-hosting

I am much confuse about [000webhost](http://000webhost.com) database uploading I have set my database at their and accessing it with username and password perfectly. Now trying to connect with through PHP code but i am failed, getting 500 error code and no details of the error although I have also logged exception message in my connection code nuto it only showing "A Connection error has occurred" and nothing more:

```
//DB Configuration
$hostName = 'localhost';
$dbUserName = 'id143984_jw_kioskuser';
$dbPassword = '***********';
$databaseName = 'id143984_jw_kiosk';

try{
     $dbHandler = new PDO('mysql:host='. $hostName . ';dbname='. $databaseName, $dbUserName, $dbPassword);
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo '<h1>A Connection error has occurred.</h1><pre>', $e->getMessage() ,'</pre>';
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

My current DB interface at 000webhost saying me that **"Use localhost as connection hostname"**
while in [another post of 000WEbhost](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/i-get-access-denied-errors-when-trying-to-connect-to-mysql-25) saying "**Never use 'localhost' as your MySQL hostname! You can find your MySQL hostname by logging on to members area, entering control panel and clicking on MySQL icon**."

HOw do i make successfull connection?

Comment: enter the url to your mysql-server insted of "localhost"

Comment: @Blueblazer172 make sure your db configuration in your connection are correct and matches to the hosting db configuration

Comment: @Blueblazer172 https://databases.000webhost.com is the database url

Comment: @NewbeeDev how you will do this? i have matched all the things. confusion about the host name as question stated

Comment: replace "localhost" with "databases.000webhost.com"

Comment: i have done it but it didnot work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i managed to get the answer through mysql query thanks to [**Show MySQL host via SQL Command Answer at stack**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283248/show-mysql-host-via-sql-command)
I run below query and got the host name and use it in my php it worked now.

```
 select @@hostname;
    show variables where Variable_name like '%host%';
```

Comment: where and to run this query to get host name of 000webhost free

Answer (score -2):

```
$hostName = 'mysql6.000webhosting.com';
$dbUserName = 'id143984_jw_kioskuser';
$dbPassword = '***********';
$databaseName = 'id143984_jw_kiosk';



$con = mysql_connect($hostName,$dbUserName,$dbPassword);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }`enter code here`

mysql_select_db("$databaseName",$con);
```

this should give you the real reason and note the correct host name

Comment: where did you find host name? and i am not willing to use old sql connection. i want pdo