# How do I overcome this sql connectivity error with python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I am not able to connect to `MySQL` sever using `python` it gives and error which says

> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1130, "Host 'LAPTOP-0HDEGFV9' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")

The code I'm using:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="LAPTOP-0HDEGFV9",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="abcd13de",  
                     db="testing")        # name of the data base


cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * Employee")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row[0])

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an authorization problem not a connectivity problem. Is the db running locally? If not, confirm with the admin where it is hosted. If so, try changing the host parameter to `127.0.0.1`?

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283266/10553976) the admin can get the hostname by running:

```
select @@hostname;
show variables where Variable_name like '%host%';
```

If the connection was timing out you could try setting the `connect_timeout` kwarg but that's already `None` by default.

Comment: It is running on my laptop

Comment: Try changing the hostname as described in my answer.

Comment: That's a separate question but assuming `Employee` is a real table in the db: `SELECT * FROM Employee`

Comment: @CharlesLandau I believe you are thinking of `127.0.0.1`.